# Real Analysis: Does a continuous function of a vector sequence converging imply the vector sequence converges?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I have a compact set $E \subset {\rm I\!R}^{n}$.
$\textit{f} : {\rm I\!R}^{n} \rightarrow {\rm I\!R}^{m}$ is a continuous function on ${\rm I\!R}^{n}$.

I need to prove that if you have a sequence in $E$, $(x_{i})_{i=0}^{\infty}$ such that the limit of $\textit{f}(x_{i})$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$ is $\textit{f}(x)$ then the limit of $(x_{i})_{i=0}^{\infty}$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$ is $x$.

I have a picture in my head as to why it isn't true:
imagine f(xi) converged to f(x). x  is in E as f is only defined on E. If xi didn't converge to x, then it would mean that there exists an epsilon such that for all natural numbers, N, there exists an i greater than N such that ||xi - x|| is bigger or equal to epsilon. i.e. the sequence doesn't stay inside that epsilon ball around x.
but f is continuous, so for it to converge to f(x) but for xi to never stay inside the epsilon ball it would seem as if f(xi) would actually be jumping around?

I thought that I'd need to a) show $(x_{i})_{i=0}^{\infty}$ actually converges
and then b) show it converges to $x$.

I just can't formulate a proof for this (or perhaps disprove it...? I've pondered on it for so long I'm not sure anymore.)

Comment: if it's an exercise there is probably a missing condition, like injectivity of $f$?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. For a counterexample, take $n=m=1$, $E=[0,1]$, $f(x)=0$, and $$x_n=\frac12\left(1+(-1)^n\right).$$ Then clearly $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=0$, but
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n = 1 $$
while
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n = 0,$$
so $x_n$ does not converge.